Can anyone identify what _kind_ of radio this Viking "Mercury" radio is?
I'm usually pretty good at identifying old gear, but this one baffled me - and without a model number, Googling is basically useless.
The front panel contains volume and squelch, but that's it.  I didn't see any obvious way to tune this radio, so my guess was that this is some kind of fixed-frequency receiver, possibly a weather radio or maybe a scanner with hard-wired frequencies?
I know enough about vintage equipment to know I don't want to just 'turn it on' without first opening it and giving it the once over.  So I'm not going to just fire-it-up and see what happens.
Can anyone tell me, what kind of radio am I looking at?



It could be a base station as well.  Are there any crystals inside?

@Duston, Just to explain, I'm unable to open the rig at this time and investigate further.  I hope at some point to be able to find space on my bench and open it, clean it up, and maybe even turn it on - but that's out of scope at the moment.  I figured a few quick photos and a post on Stack would be the easiest thing for now...

I have never seen one of these, but it looks enough like receivers that I have seen and owned that I can make a reasonable educated guess.
It appears to be a single channel alert-monitor receiver or just monitor receiver.  These were made in the vacuum tube and early solid state eras.  They were made by Motorola, Plectron, and others.  Google Motorola or Plectron alert monitor for examples.
A typical use would be to listen on a single dispatch channel to alert respond from home volunteer fire fighters.  Or just to monitor a dispatch channel.  I have Motorolas that were made to order for a specific crystal controlled frequency.  They were often built for low band VHF but could also be high band.  It should be possible to change the crystal, but you are kind of stuck with the frequency band.
Some of these receivers have an option for tone alerting.  That is, a specific tone or tone sequence would be transmitted over the dispatch channel to open the squelch on the receiver.  Usually, receivers with these options would a couple of extra swiches for alert/monitor mode and arm/reset to control the alerting.
The Motorola that I have is set up for the option of 110VAC or 12VDC power.  Your unit is equipped with an 8-pin Cinch-Jones plug which may offer similar options.  You said you are familiar with vintage equipment, so you know to be careful with the high voltages.
